# Opening SAP via python

Tags: python

I have sucessfully managed to open SAP, but I am struggling to make python click on the logon button that appears when the program is opened. How could I achieve that?

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe')

# I would like python to press the logon button in the window that has just been opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SAP\\FrontEnd\\SAPgui\\sapshcut.exe', '-system=PE1', '-client=500', '-user=user', '-pw=password', '-language=EN'])
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, python is not exactly the best language when it comes to automate windows in "makro-style" maybe you could use something lilke AutoHotkey (AHK) for that.

For completion's sake:
There seem to be python modules like PyAutoGUI which could help you achieve what you want.
Or you could import win32api and try to control windows that way.

If you really try to automate SAP with python you should try to get information about an official API of SAP which you could call.
Maybe this will help: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/09/connecting-python-with-sap-step-by-step-guide/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any examples of how to apply PyAutoGUI or win32api in this particular case?

Comment: No sorry. I also just googled it. To give a better answer you should probably edit your question and provide a little more context. If it is only the automated login you are trying to achieve, this "mouse-clicking" approach might work. But I thinki would be quite ugly as sometimes the SAP window will not be at the same position and you must account for that.

Comment: If it is however some further functionality after the login you are trying to achieve, I think it's entirely a bad idea to try to automat this with this kind of approach. You save yourself enormous amounts of pain if you do it the intended way (API) from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use win32com to connect to the SAPGUI.

Find the "Script Recording and Playback" in your SAP menu to record your SAP transactions in a script. Find that script you can see all your transaction in code.
[image: Script Recording]

Use the [SAPGUI with Python](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/19/how-to-use-sap-gui-scripting-inside-python-programming-language/) example to create a session on an opened SAP. Replace the SAP script in that example with your recorded script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    import win32com.client
    import subprocess
    import sys

    def saplogin():

        try:

            path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
            sap = subprocess.Popen(path)
            time.sleep(10)

            SapGuiAuto = win32com.client.GetObject('SAPGUI')
            if not type(SapGuiAuto) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                return

            application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
            if not type(application) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return
            connection = application.OpenConnection("PCL", True)

            if not type(connection) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                application = None
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return

            session = connection.Children(0)
            if not type(session) == win32com.client.CDispatch:
                connection = None
                application = None
                SapGuiAuto = None
                return

            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME").text = "username"
            session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE").text = "password"
            session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey(0)
            
            print(sys.exc_info())

        finally:
            session = None
            connection = None
            application = None
            SapGuiAuto = None
    saplogin()
```